# Gathering data from raw data table with multiple criteria

Tags: worksheet-function, database, microsoft-excel-2019

I am coming up empty handed trying to formulate a string to pull specific training data from a huge list.

Raw Data has over 4800 rows

1. Column A has over 70 Unique Names
2. Column B has over 74 Unique Systems
3. Column C has 5 different unique training levels
4. Column D has Yes or NO for training having been completed.

I am wanting to pull the data to another sheet which will give me a total completion % for each type of training and the overall for each. This is already done.

The issue is updating it weekly is pretty time consuming manually going through each of the Systems, Training levels, and Names. I have tried a few ways but hit road blocks with errors or "You've entered too many arguments for this function"

I am currently trying to use something along the lines:

=IF(ISTEXT(SHEET2!A:A),"NAME"*ISTEXT(SHEET2!B:B),"SYSTEM"*ISTEXT(SHEET2!C:C),"SHEET2"*ISTEXT(SHEET2!D:D),"YES","1","0")

Pretty much saying:
IF (NAME1) AND (SYSTEM1) AND (TRAININGLEVEL1) AND (YES) (return value 1 if true)(return value 0 if false

A total of 4 Variables that I need to match up to return the value 1 or 0 depending if it is true or not. This is of course going to be for about 13 people, 66 systems, 4 training levels, and their corresponding Yes/No for being completed.

If there is an easier way to pull the data for what I am trying to do, I am all EARS. I am most likely overthinking this entirely, but I know there is a way, it's literally what excel was made to do!

Comment: It’s worth stating that there are dynamic array features in Excel O365 that would profoundly simplify this on a level I can’t even put into words.  It may not be possible in your situation but if you are spending more than 5 minutes a month dealing with this, it would be the most valuable investment of a hundred bucks or less you can imagine.  And I want to be encouraging and not sound insensitive, but the IF formula in your question, even if it were restructured in the proper number of arguments, does not say anything similar to your “pretty much saying” description.

Comment: I figured that would be the case, as when looking for solutions i saw a few involving Dynamic Arrays, but this is a Company laptop and pretty restrictive. I will see if they offer it and try that way!